# Storing data in a link table

Tags: mysql, database-design

Supoose I have the following:

```
tbl_options
===========
id    name
1     experience
2     languages
3     hourly_rate


tbl_option_attributes
=====================
id    option_id    name          value
1     1            beginner      1
2     1            advanced      2
3     2            english       1
4     2            french        2
5     2            spanish       3
6     3            £10 p/h       10
7     3            £20 p/h       20


tbl_user_options
================
user_id    option_id    value
1          1            2
1          2            1
1          2            2
1          2            3
1          3            20
```

In the above example tbl_user_options stores option data for the user. We can store multiple entries for some options.

Now I wish to extend this, i.e. for "languages" I want the user to be able to specify their proficiency in a language (basic/intermediate/advanced). There will also be other fields that will have extended attributes.

So my question is, can these extended attributes be stored in the same table (tbl_user_options) or do I need to create more tables? Obviously if I put in a field "language_proficiency" it won't apply to the other fields. But this way I only have one user options table to manage. What do you think?

EDIT: This is what I propose

```
tbl_user_options
================
user_id    option_id    value     lang_prof
1          1            2         null
1          2            1         2
1          2            2         3
1          2            3         3
1          3            20        null
```

Answer (score 1):

My gut instinct would be to split the User/Language/Proficiency relationship out into its own tables. Even if you kept it in the same table with your other options, you'd need to write special code to handle the language case, so you might as well use a new table structure.

Comment: @GSTAR: I'm not sure there's a definitive right/wrong answer in this situation. If you're comfortable with that approach, I see no real problem with it.

Comment: Cool. It's always a good idea to get other people's view, though I did have feeling it would be one of those down to personal preference :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless your data model is in constant flux, I would rather have `tbl_languages` and `tabl_user_languages` tables to store those types of data:

```
tbl_languages
================
lang_id    name
1          English
2          French
3          Spanish

tbl_user_languages
================
user_id    lang_id      proficiency  hourly_rate
1          1            1            20
1          2            2            10
2          2            1            15
2          2            3            20
3          3            2            10
```

Designing a system that is "too generic" is a Turing tarpit trap for a relational SQL database. A document-based database is better suited to arbitrary key-value stores.

Excepting certain optimisations, your database model should match your domain model as closely as possible to minimise the object-relational impedance mismatch.

This design lets you display a sensible table of user language proficiencies and hourly rates with only two inner joins:

```
SELECT
    ul.user_id,
    u.name,
    l.name,
    ul.proficiency,
    ul.hourly_rate
FROM tbl_user_languages ul
INNER JOIN tbl_languages l
    ON l.lang_id = ul.lang_id
INNER JOIN tbl_users u
    ON u.user_id = ul.user_id
ORDER BY
    l.name, u.hour
```

Optionally you can split out a list of language proficiencies into a `tbl_profiencies` table, where `1 == Beginner`, `2 == Advanced`, `3 == Expert` and join it onto `tbl_user_languages`.

Comment: I see. But my concern in this situation would be the number of extra tables to manage. As there are more fields that have additional attribute data there could be as many as 8-10 tables, as opposed to only two.

Comment: Can you provide examples of some other attributes? Usually these types of attributes pertain to a specific user or language, which should only be an extra column in the corresponding table (assuming one-to-one data). If the attribute values are primarily enumerations (eg. "Low", "Medium", "High"), store only the value as a tinyint and map the value to descriptive text in your presentation layer. Managing 8-10 tables in a RDBMS is not uncommon. To speed up queries, use views to join the data.

Comment: Yes they are just enumerations, similar to the languages. Check out my edit as it might give a better idea of what I mean.

Comment: If you are only using a column like `lang_prof` for a few records, then you should [normalise your data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) with a separate table for that attribute. Don't use a SQL table for a generic key-value data store as this defies the point of a relational database. If your attributes are completely arbitrary (though they almost never are), look into db4o or CouchDB for a document-based data store.

Answer (score -1):

i'm thinking it's a mistake to put "languages" as an option. while reading your text it seems to me that english is an option, and it might have an attribute from option_attributes.